# using javascript generators with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, koa

I have a generator function that I am trying to unit test.  The function I am testing takes a generator as a method argument too.

I can run `mocha --harmony` so it runs the tests however, I have put a generator function in my test file which will be the function I will pass to the function I am testing but mocha throws an error saying it does not understand `*` on my test file.

For example,

```
    function mytestgenerator() * {
        return "next gen"
    }

    describe('my app', function () {
        describe('important method', function () {
            it('should return -1', function () {
                var result = sut(mytestgenerator);
            })
        })
    })


/Users/jonathan/Projects/myapp/test/index_spec.js:9
function mytestgenerator() * {
               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is in the wrong place [for a generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

It should be just after the `function` keyword, before the name or parameters.

```
function * mytestgenerator() {
    return "next gen";
}
```

---

If it still isn't recognized, make sure you're using Node 0.11 or later, as `--harmony` doesn't include generators in previous versions.